# RxJava - как в ViewModel передать метод из Репозитория в LiveData и указать потоки

Tags: java, android, rxjava, android-room, viewmodel

In Dao:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :status_debil ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    Single<List<Person>> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_debil);
```

In Repo:

```
public class PersonRepository {
    public Single<List<Person>> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_debil) {
        return mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom(status_debil);
    }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository mRepository;
    //declaring variables
    public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
        //initializing variables
    }
    //methods
}
```

Что и где мне нужно написать в ViewModel, чтобы дернуть метод из Репозитория (и указать второстепенный поток) и передать ответ в LiveData?

Comment: А почему бы не получить `LiveData` сразу из dao? Пролистайте этот тренинг - он даст вам общее представление что к чему: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при изменениях в базе список уже НЕ обновлялся.